# Using a variable in a findall search

Tags: python, regex, findall, cad, step

Ok so I am reading a variable from a dictionary (DoL) I have created as such:

```
for i in DoL.keys():
    fobId = DoL["{}".format(i)]["FaceOuterBound"]
```

So lets say, on the first iteration through DoL:

```
fobId = 194
```

I have tried to create a regex findall expression which includes the variable `fobId`:

```
edgeloop_txt = re.findall(r'^#'+str(fobId)+r'.*#(\d+).*;', text)
```

In order to find the line in `text` which begins with #`fobId`:

```
#194 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE', #159, .T. ) ;
```

And finally extract the number #159

My output `print(edgeloop_txt)` just gives me empty lists:

```
[]
[] 
[]
...
```

**EDIT (providing an MCVE):**

Sample text:

```
...
#190 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE',  ( -1.000000000000000000, -0.0000000000000000000, -0.0000000000000000000 ) ) ;
#191 = DATE_AND_TIME ( #277, #349 ) ;
#192 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE', *, *, #253, .T. ) ;
#193 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE',  ( 75.00000000000000000, 35.00000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000000 ) ) ;
#194 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE', #159, .T. ) ;
#195 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE', *, *, #205, .T. ) ;
#196 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE',  ( 0.0000000000000000000, 35.00000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000000 ) ) ;
...
```

Code I am using:

```
for i in DoL.keys():
    fobId = DoL["{}".format(i)]["FaceOuterBound"]
    edgeloop_txt = re.findall(r'^#'+str(fobId)+r'.*#(\d+).*;', text)
    print(edgeloop_txt)
```

Where DoL is a dictionary as such:

```
{'Face0': {'AdvancedFace': 12, 'FaceOuterBound': 194, 'Plane': 326}, 
'Face1': {'AdvancedFace': 73, 'FaceOuterBound': 53, 'Plane': 230}, 
'Face2': {'AdvancedFace': 99, 'FaceOuterBound': 121, 'Plane': 123}, 
'Face3': {'AdvancedFace': 131, 'FaceOuterBound': 268, 'Plane': 270}, 
...
'Face9': {'AdvancedFace': 358, 'FaceOuterBound': 9, 'Plane': 363}}
```

Comment: what's your sample text looklike?

Comment: @MCBama sample text is `#194 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE', #159, .T. ) ;`

Comment: Do this have to be with regex?

Comment: Ok, are you reading from a file or is the text object already in existence? You might want to post a complete code snippet (a MCVE as described by stack's help center)

Comment: I fail to see what the dictionary has to do with the question. The basic thing [works](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/test)

Comment: Did you debug and print the value of both the `text` and `fobId` in each iteration?

Comment: Apologies if I am coming across unclearly, I am extremely new to programming in general!

@trincot I can see how that works, and that is what I want to achieve. I am reading the `fobId` value from a previously created dictionary which you can now see in the edited post.

Comment: Can you please print the dictionary (`print(DoL)`)?  The output format you use for it is strange.

Comment: @trincot I have just edited to post to show `print(DoL)`. To make you aware it is a dictionary within a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I've figured out your problem. You're using a large block of text but your regex has a `^` in it indicating beginning of line. The problem is you're not iterating over lines you're parsing the entire text at once and because you're doing that your regex line start character is preventing you from finding your matches.

Your options are to either iterate over your text line by line or simply remove the `^` from your regex.

Example of line by line iteration:

```
for key,val in DoL.items():
  fobId = val["FaceOuterBound"]
  matches = []
  for line in text.splitlines():
    # split text into lines and compare to each line
    response = re.match(r'^#'+str(fobId)+r'.*#(\d+).*;', line)
    # if a match was found, store it in list of matches
    if response: matches.append(response[1])
  print(matches) # ['159']
```

Comment: So I took the ^ out of the regex..

The first line of the output becomes:
    `['326', '159']`

So the regex seems to be picking up the lines where it finds #194 in any position, rather than only the lines which **begin** with #194...

Comment: @DarrenTaggart Yeah you might need to also modify your regex to include a search for line breaks if you don't want to iterate over the lines by themselves. I'll add an example line iteration tool but it'll look a bit more complicated and will probably have a longer run-time.

Comment: I was able to solve solve the problem by simply adding a `\n` to the beginning of the regex. However now I am running into an issue where the number #14 will also pick up #140, #141, #142.. and so on!

Comment: Your problem is your regex. The easiest one is probably going to be this: `r'#'+str(fobId)+r' = .*#(\d+).*;'` Adding the equals sign in there should guarantee you get the numbers you're looking for